# What is the degeneracy for two spin 1/2 DISTINGUISHABLE particles in ground state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body

Suppose two particles are non-interacting and under the same potential.
The Hamiltonian doesn't contain spin terms. We suppose the one-particle states are $\psi_n(x)$ with $E_n=n^2K$

For me, it is like the ground  state has infinity degenracies because of

Spatial part: $\psi_1(x_1)\psi_1(x_2)$

spin part: $\chi(1,2)$ could be **any** linear combination of singlet and triplet state $|1-1\rangle,|10\rangle,|1+1\rangle,$ and $|00\rangle$.

However, my textbook claims the ground state has only 4 degeneracies.

Comment: What is your definition of "degeneracy", i.e. why do you think it is infinite here?

Comment: Oh, I might have known the mistake. The degenerate states have to be linear independent! I previously thought like $\psi_{1}(x_1)\psi_1(x_2)(1/\sqrt{2}|1-1\rangle+1/\sqrt{2}|00\rangle)$ is also an eigenstate of H.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_energy_levels, "The dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to that eigenvalue is known as its degree of degeneracy". This is not the **number** of the states with the ground state energy but the **number of linearly independent states**. In the problem you consider, there are 4 linearly independent basis vectors, so the degree of degeneracy is 4.

Answer (score 0):

The *degeneracy* of the ground state does not refer to the number of distinct vectors with the ground state energy (which as you say, is obviously infinite) but rather the dimension of the subspace of such vectors.  Since each particle could be spin-up or spin-down, this space is 4-dimensional; a generic vector with the ground state energy takes the form
$$\Psi(\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2) = \psi_1(\mathbf x_1)\psi_1(\mathbf x_2) \big(c_1\left|\uparrow\uparrow\right>+c_2\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right>+c_3\left|\downarrow\uparrow\right>+c_4\left|\downarrow\downarrow\right>\big)$$
with the $c_i$'s arbitrary constants.

---

As a separate point, the standard basis we use to describe the spin states of a pair of spin-1/2 particles is a simultaneous eigenbasis of the total spin $S^2\equiv (\mathbf S_1+\mathbf S_2)^2$ and $S_z \equiv S_{1,z}+ S_{2,z}$, whereby
$$S^2|s,m\rangle = s(s+1)|s,m\rangle \qquad S_z|s,m\rangle = m$$
These four basis vectors can be separated into the (antisymmetric) spin singlet
$$|0,0\rangle = \frac{\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right>-\left|\downarrow\uparrow\right>}{\sqrt{2}}$$
and (symmetric) spin triplet
$$|1,-1\rangle = \left|\downarrow\downarrow\right> \qquad |1,0\rangle = \frac{\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right>+\left|\downarrow\uparrow\right>}{\sqrt{2}} \qquad |1,1\rangle = \left|\uparrow\uparrow\right>$$

The fact that the tensor product of two 2-dimensional spaces (correspoding the individual spin-1/2 particles) results in a direct sum of a 1-dimensional subspace (with spin-0) and a 3-dimensional subspace (with spin-1) is written symbolically as $2\otimes 2 = 1 \oplus 3$.